# Get the first positive coefficient in polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

I have Polynomial $F(x) = \sum_{i \leq n}{a_ix^i}$. How to get the first $a_i > 0$?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

suppose our polynomial is

```
   pol = -6 x^8 + 3 x^2 + 2 x^3 - 4 x^5 + 6 x^4 - 2 x^6 - 2 x^7 - 3 x
```

We can get the first positive coefficient as follows:

```
Cases[CoefficientList[pol, x], n_ /; Positive[n], Infinity, 1]
```

To get both the `a` and the corresponding `i` here's an elaborate function that lets you choose how many you want to select:

```
coeff[{pol_, x_} /; PolynomialQ[pol, x], k_Integer] := 
 With[{ex = Exponent[pol, x, List], cf = DeleteCases[CoefficientList[pol, x], 0]},
  Cases[Transpose[{cf, ex}], {_?Positive, _}, Infinity, k]]
```

Usage:

```
coeff[{pol, x}, 1]
```

> {{3, 2}}

```
coeff[{pol, x}, 2]
```

> {{3, 2}, {2, 3}}

This also works if your polynomial is just `pol = x`

```
coeff[{x, x}, 1]
```

> {{1, 1}}

Comment: Can we get the corresponding i as well?

Comment: @Loi.Luu. Yes we can. I'll add that now

Comment: yeah, take your time :)

Comment: Have you tried with F(x) = x yet? It gives {} instead

Comment: @Loi.Luu Please see my update.

Answer (score 2):

With my limited Mathematica knowledge, I would do something like:

```
First[Select[CoefficientList[polynomial, x], Positive]]
```

Comment: Should mention that this will die if you have no positive coefficients.  I suppose add a bit of fidgety stuff to deal with this if you aren't sure about the form of your input.

Comment: can we get the index i also?

Answer (score 2):

Function Select has a nice third argument indication how many object that meet your requiremenrts should be taken. So I think one of the veriants to solve the problem is

```
Select[CoefficientList[pol, x], Positive, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Some variants:
If empty set ok for single variable power series:

```
Cases[CoefficientList[pol,x],_?Positive,1,1];
```

If exponent required,

```
Cases[Reverse@CoefficientRules[pol],Rule[a_,b_?Positive]->(a->b),1,1]
```

Assuming (in x):

```
First@(Cases[
    CoefficientList[pol, x], _?
     Positive] /. {} -> {"No positive coefficient"})
```

Or if exponent and coefficient required

```
Last@(Cases[CoefficientRules[pol], 
  Rule[{e_}, x_?Positive] -> {e -> x}]/.{} -> {"No positive coefficient"})
```